# 1.15.2 - How do I test for if a player's inventory is open?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to do something that gives you mining fatigue while your inventory is not open, but stops whenever it is opened. I would appreciate some help with this. Is there an NBT tag for this?

Comment: Wouldn't that be the same as having mining fatigue all the time? When the inventory is open, you can't mine anyway.

Comment: It is probably impossible. You can detect when something in the inventory changes, but that's it.

Comment: I wanted this so that they couldn't mine blocks, but couldn't see any visible effects (on the side of the inventory GUI)

Comment: Then a resource pack is probably your only option. Or maybe Adventure mode, but that depends on what other things the players need to do.

Comment: mining fatigue doesn't prevent mining blocks, it just takes a long time. Adventure mode or chunk protection is your best bet if you dont want blocks destroyed

Comment: @Rapitor Sure, but if the wiki and my calculations are correct, then it takes 117047642866854295674666898962796109064121568068438 years to mine a single snow layer with an Efficiency 5 Netherite shovel while having Haste 2 and Mining fatigue 127. Edit 1: Actually, the wiki contradicts itself. It might also just take 0.1 seconds then. Hmmm… Edit 2: According to my test this takes 4 seconds. So the wiki is wrong in both ways. I'll see if I can fix that, after figuring out what the correct formula is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they're never meant to mine any blocks, just put them in Adventure mode.

If they're meant to be able to mine a certain type of block, tools have NBT tags that allow them to mine one type of block only (**they still need to be in Adventure mode)**:

```
1.12-: /give @p minecraft:diamond_pickaxe 1 0 {CanDestroy:["BLOCK_HERE"]}
1.13+: /give @p minecraft:diamond_pickaxe{CanDestroy:["minecraft:BLOCK_HERE"]} 1
```

If they're only not meant to be able to mine blocks in a certain area, put pressure plates activating Adventure mode at the entrance to it, and activating Survival Mode at the exit to it.

Comment: Or use a command with a radius around the area, setting a scoreboard which controls their game mode. That way there's no ugly pressure plates and you can have as many of them as you want.